# Join two routers / internet connections under one SSID

Tags: networking, router, printer, isp, redundancy

**I have two networks. 
A & B.**

Both A & B have WWW access via independent ISPs.

A is a fast network.
B has the printers.

In theory I'd like to join the networks under one router/SSID and use ISP A unless there is an outage, where I would have the system switch to ISP B.

Ideas? I am pretty technical, just not with networking.

Comment: How are both networks connected? Only over the internet or are they in physical proximity?

Comment: Look into pfsense/opensense, it has exactly this functionality. You could also go with a off the shelf solution like a dual wan router with failover support